# Error installing @tensorflow/tfjs-node on Mac OS X

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, npm, macos-catalina

Can't install tensorflow js for node, but tfjs works (`npm install @tensorflow/tfjs`)

running `npm i @tensorflow/tfjs-node` returns [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UucWu.png)

Here's the debug [log](https://pastebin.com/KRW2dqzf)

os: `macOs Catalina Version 10.15.7`

node.js: `v16.15.1`

npm: `8.12.2`

Any help at all would be great!

Comment: have you tried installing node-pre-gyp as the error suggests?

Comment: yep, i did it but it still doesnt work 